# Tensorflow lite model maker for react native

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, image-segmentation, tflite

I am building a mobile app for scanning receipts from images.
I collected enough datasets for the app and app is also almost completed.
I tried with some tflite models which are free open sourced online but in my case of scanning receipts, it requires new kind of model. So I want to know how to make a tflite model with my own datasets and custom requirements.

Thanks for your time.

I've tried with the following.  But I can't find how to customized it.

https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/modify/model_maker

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  
The tflite model maker guide you're referring to says that if your task isn't listed, you need to train a custom TF model and convert it to tflite manually. I would say, your task is OCR (or form recognition, to be specific), I'm not sure if there are any good TF OCR models out there though.

Comment: Thank you for consideration. I already have done research on how to convert TF model to tflite manually. But I can't train custom TF model.